# How do I use Perl's grep function with an array?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, list, grep

I am trying to use the grep function in Perl to find the number of matches for a regexp in an array. I know grep is supposed to take a list as its parameter, but unfortunately the data I am trying to access is in the form of an array. Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
using strict;
using warnings;

my @test = qw(AAA AAB AAC);
my @test2 = ["AAA", "AAB", "AAC"];

my @results = grep(m/AA./, @test);
my @results2 = grep(m/AA./, @test2);

print @results . "\n";
print @results2 . "\n";
```

The first print puts out 3 since every member of the list matches. The second print prints out 0 which I'm assuming is because grep does not like the array. Is there an alternative I should be using or is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@test2` consist of exactly one element which is array reference, and regex forces stringification, something you probably didn't expect,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test = qw(AAA AAB AAC);
my @test2 = ["AAA", "AAB", "AAC"];

print "$_\n" for @test;
print "$_\n" for @test2;
```

output

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
ARRAY(0x85bfda8)
```

Use `my @test2 = ("AAA", "AAB", "AAC");` or `quote word` operator alternative `my @test2 = qw(AAA AAB AAC);`

Comment: This makes sense. I did not realize that that the square brackets created a reference to an array rather than just filling in its indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `[ ... ]` defines a reference to an array, not a list, and your declaration

```
my @test2 = ["AAA", "AAB", "AAC"];
```

is equivalent to

```
my @test2;
$test2[0] = ["AAA", "AAB", "AAC"];
```

You probably wanted to assign a list of 3 elements to `@test2`. The way to do this is with `( ... )` notation.

```
my @test2 = ('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intended the variable "`@test2`" to be an [array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) (since `[ ]` is the anonymous array constructor here) then you should give it a name like `$test2` (i.e. a scalar variable) and then dereference it when using `grep`:

```
my $test2 = ["AAA", "AAB", "AAC"];

my @results = grep(m/AA./, @test);
my @results2 = grep(m/AA./, @$test2);
```

If you then print `@results` and `@results2` concatenating them with "`."\n";` this creates scalar context for your output. Scalar context for an array will show the number of elements in the array. If you use `join` to print it will show the elements:

```
print join "\n", @results2 ;
```

**output:**

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
```

The documentation in [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) explains why references are a good thing ;-)